# How can i used "DevExpress v10.2" in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net

How can i used "DevExpress v10.2" in VS2010? and what the reference need to add in webconfig file.

Comment: Did you try googleing? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the assembilies in your project. You also need to include following sections in your web.config

```
<httpModules>
<add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
</httpModules>


<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```